How to Verify User Email and Retrieve Full Name Using MSAL Authentication and Azure Functions
I'm working on an application where users log in using MSAL authentication, and during registration, I've granted the scope of user.ReadBasic.All permission for the Microsoft Graph API. Now, I need to verify if the provided user email (login user and email provided by login user to verfiy are different) belongs to the same tenant and, if verified, retrieve their full name.
Here's my current approach:

Frontend: Users log in using MSAL authentication.
Backend (Azure Function Endpoint API): I receive the email to verify and the access token in the request. I then decode the token to extract the user's email.
Next, I compare the domain of the provided email with the domain extracted from the decoded token. If they match, I consider the email verified.

However, this approach only verifies if the email domain matches the tenant, which doesn't guarantee that the email belongs to an actual user. Instead, I need to ensure the email belongs to a valid user within the tenant and retrieve their full name.
Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Specifically, how can I validate the user's email and retrieve their full name using MSAL authentication and Azure Functions?
following is my code where I have removed comparison and jwt decode logic.
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"; 

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const { email } = req.body;
            const token = req.headers.authorization;

            if (!token || !email) {
                context.res = {
                    status: 400,
                    body: "Token in the 'Authorization' header and email in the request body are required."
                };
                return;
            }
            const bearerToken = token.split(' ')[1];

            // we decode jwt token to get tenantid and email

            if (!decoded || decoded.tid !== tenantId) {
                context.res = {
                    status: 403,
                    body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Unauthorized: Invalid token or tenant' })
                };
                return;
            }

            const userEmail = decoded.preferred_username;
            if (typeof userEmail !== 'string' || typeof email !== 'string') {
                context.res = {
                    status: 400,
                    body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Invalid email format' })
                };
                return;
            }

            // we check email domain comparison here 

            if (providedDomain !== tokenDomain) {
                context.res = {
                    status: 400,
                    body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Email does not match the tenant. Verification failed.' })
                };
                return;
            }
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Email matches the tenant. Verification successful.' })
            };

        } catch (error) {
            context.log.error('Token verification error:', error.message);
            context.res = {
                status: 401,
                body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Invalid token' })
            };
        }
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 405,
            body: "Method Not Allowed"
        };
    }
};


Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
All I am trying to do is create an Azure Function API that checks whether an email is valid or not when a login user from the same tenant sends a request to verify other email (so that user can exclude non verified email for any kind of registration within company).

You need to make a request to the Graph API to retrieve the user's basic profile. The field you need to compare is mail.
If the email address in the decoded token is an email alias of the user, and you want to allow using email aliases, you will need the User.Read.All permission. This will allow you retrieve the full profile, which contains an array of proxyAddresses. You'll need to trim the "SMTP:" portion from the start of the values returned, or tack "SMTP:" to the start of the email from the token in your comparison.
Here's some code to retrieve the user's profile:
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const https = require('https');

// MSAL configuration
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'your_client_id',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id',
        clientSecret: 'your_client_secret'
    }
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const userEmail = req.query.email; // Get user's email address from request query

    if (!userEmail) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: 'User email address is required'
        };
        return;
    }

    // Acquire a token for the Microsoft Graph API
    const tokenRequest = {
        scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    };

    try {
        const tokenResponse = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest);

        // Microsoft Graph API endpoint for specific user profile
        const graphApiEndpoint = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userEmail}`;

        const options = {
            hostname: 'graph.microsoft.com',
            path: `/v1.0/users/${userEmail}`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`
            }
        };

        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            let data = '';

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                const userProfile = JSON.parse(data);
                context.res = {
                    body: {
                        id: userProfile.id,
                        displayName: userProfile.displayName,
                        givenName: userProfile.givenName,
                        surname: userProfile.surname,
                        mail: userProfile.mail
                    }
                };
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: error.message
            };
        });

        req.end();
    } catch (error) {
        context.res = {
            status: error.response ? error.response.status : 500,
            body: error.response ? error.response.data : 'Internal Server Error'
        };
    }
};

